# UIImage not showing up on iPad Device, but it shows up on the iPad Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5, uiimage

Here is the code that I am using. Keep in mind, this works just fine in the simulator. However, when I run the same code when testing on my iPad device, it doesn't load the image. Why could this be?

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.net/folder/Photos/thumbnails/IMG_1780.JPG"];
UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:url];

if (cachedImage)
{
    // Use the cached image immediatly
}
else
{
    // Start an async download
    [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self];
}


UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80+196, 5, 192, 192)];
[button setImage:cachedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:button];
return cell;
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Edit: Altered Code, still works in Sim, but not on device.

```
    - (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // Do something with the downloaded image
    //testImage = image;
    testButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80+196, 5, 192, 192)];
    [testButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.net/album/Photos/thumbnails/IMG_1780.JPG"];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:url];
    [self webImageManager:manager didFinishWithImage:cachedImage];
    if (cachedImage)
    {
        // Use the cached image immediatly
        //[self webImageManager:manager didFinishWithImage:cachedImage];
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80+196, 5, 192, 192)];
        [button setImage:cachedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:testButton];
    }
    else
    {
        // Start an async download
        [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Never having used SDWebImageManager but just having a quick look at it, it looks like you're doing everything right! On the other hand, it's not working so...

I had a similar problem to this once, and after much tearing out of hair, I eventually discovered that the filing systems used on the device & the simulator are different - on your iPad I believe it's case sensitive, but not on the simulator. Double-check the case of the file names, it might make a difference.

Edit - also, I was assuming you're trying to use the cached image (which is why it appeared immediately), but if you're downloading one then I expect your button initialising code is premature.

Another Edit - Delegates!

Do you know about using the delegate of the SDWebImageManager? It probably has a method which it calls when the image has downloaded - you need to implement SDWebImageManager delegate protocol in your class where you're setting up the buttons, etc - there will be a method something like -(void)imageDidFinishDownloading:(UIImage *)myImage which you'll have to include, and that's where you need to put the images into the buttons.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense! I did try implementing this guy (by implement I just mean add this snippet to my code, nothing more).

- (void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // Do something with the downloaded image
    testImage = image;
    
}

To no help... I attempted to set the loaded image equal to a global uiimage testImage that I use when creating the buttons, though it did not work even in the simulator. I most likely made a small mistake.

Comment: I think I added in what you described in my altered code above. If you could take a look at it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you checked if the delegate method is being called? Also, did you check the case of the filename?

Comment: Having another look at your code, I've just noticed that the buttons are in table cells, which means that the easiest (probably) way will be to store the downloaded images in an array (1 element per row) and reload the table when the delegate method is called and (you'll have to!) set the button images there, otherwise you're creating a button for nowhere - without seeing more code, I don't know how you'll know which row the image is for...

Answer (score 0):

May be a little too obvious but, have you checked if your iPad has an internet connection?

Comment: Yeah, I wish it was that easy. :) All connected.

Comment: If you think of anything else, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The async download may not be finished when you try to create the UIButton. The last piece of code should be called after the download is completed and inside the `if` statement (as far as i can see from this code).

Answer (score 0):

Easier to write a new answer than edit my last one.

Here's a bit of code which might be useful -

```
-(void)webImageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager didFinishWithImage:(UIImage *)image {

    // unless you have a way to know which row it's going into, we'll just add it to the end of the array

    [downloadedImages addObject:image];

    [myTable reloadData];

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [downloadedImages count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    UIImage *theImage = [downloadedImages objectAtIndex:row];

    UIButton *testButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80+196, 5, 192, 192)] autorelease];
    testButton.tag = row; // so we know which row the pressed button is in

    [testButton setImage:theImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:testButton];

    return cell;

}


-(void)imageSelected:(UIButton *)pressedButton {

    NSInteger row = pressedButton.tag;

    // now you know which row was pressed...
}
```

Change your code here (don't put it in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method!) -

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.net/folder/Photos/thumbnails/IMG_1780.JPG"];
UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:url];

if (cachedImage) {

    // Use the cached image immediately
    [downloadedImages addObject:cachedImage];

    [myTable reloadData];

} else {
    // Start an async download
    [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self];
}
```

Obviously it's quite basic - you'll need to add stuff to reset the table, or write the images to files if there are more than a few of them. Hope it helps!